# ASP.NET razor ternary expression on anonymous types

Tags: asp.net, razor, anonymous-types, ternary

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad ">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedAssignToId, Model.AssignToListItems,
      ViewBag.CanEditRequest ? new { @class = "form-control" } : new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
</div>
```

But I receive the following error:

> error CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'AnonymousType#1' and 'AnonymousType#2'

How can use a ternary expression on anonymous types in razor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can cast one side of the ternary expression to an `object`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedAssignToId, Model.AssignToListItems,
ViewBag.CanEditRequest ? (object)new { @class = "form-control" } : new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Or perhaps try moving the ternary expression into the anonymous type, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedAssignToId, Model.AssignToListItems,
new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = ViewBag.CanEditRequest ? null : "disabled" })
```

Comment: I did try it this way : @disabled = ViewBag.CanEditRequest ? null : "disabled", but when CanEditRequest was true it still rendered disabled="" in the select element.